# how to add horizontal property to scrollview layout

Tags: android, scrollview, android-scrollview

Please tell me how to add horizontal property to `scrollview`, I have set of buttons arranged horizontally which I need to scroll horizontally.

Comment: android:scrollbars="horizontal" use it in scroll view

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `HorizontalScrollView`

```
<HorizontalScrollView
   android:id="@+id/hsv"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_weight="0"
   android:fillViewport="true"
   android:measureAllChildren="false"
   android:scrollbars="none" >
   <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/innerLay"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="horizontal" >
   </LinearLayout>

</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using [HorizontalScrollView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html)

It's the same but horizontal.

> HorizontalScrollView only supports horizontal scrolling. For vertical scrolling, use either ScrollView or ListView.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes

Answer (score 1):

You have to take `HorizontalScrollView` for this.

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding" >

   <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/shapeLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >
    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

References:

https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/ui/horizontalscrollview/android-horizontalscrollview-example/

http://abhiandroid.com/ui/scrollview

Answer (score 0):

You can have a horizontal LinearLayout inside a HorizontalScrollView.